# While logging in through admin in Apache superset it redirects me back to login page

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-superset

I installed apache superset v1.4.1 successfully without any errors on my work machine(aws instance ec2 ubuntu 20) when i try to login through admin it redirects me back to login page...when i checked the logs it was throwing

WARNING:root:Class 'werkzeug.local.LocalProxy' is not mapped and
INFO:flask_wtf.csrf:The CSRF session token is missing.
400 Bad Request: The CSRF session token is missing.
2022-04-08 19:17:37,057:WARNING:superset.views.base:400 Bad Request: The CSRF session token is missing.

Then i edited config.py file and edited WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = True to WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = False and re-launched it by executing superset init command but still when i try to login it redirects me back to login page and now the log just shows WARNING:root:Class 'werkzeug.local.LocalProxy' is not mapped

Not able to login inside so no chance of creating any other roles(public, gamma etc)
Please anyone help me solve this issue i have been trying to solve this from 3 days

I have the same version of superset on my local ubuntu machine but everything works fine in my local machine I am able to login, able to create dashboard, other roles etc

In superset which i am facing error runs on HTTPS so do i need to make any other changes in config.py file...whereas the superset which runs fine for me is runnning on HTTP.

Comment: Did you create the admin user?`superset fab create-admin`

Comment: Hey yes I created admin user but even with those credentials it is not logging in @Kamal

Answer (score 2):

We suffered exactly the same problem for 2 days.
After our hard work

disabling both settings fixes the login problem.

```
# Comment settings as below:
#SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = "None"
#SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

Explanation for the above configs

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE: (default: "Lax") Prevents the browser from sending this cookie along with cross-site requests.
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE: (default: False) Browsers will only send cookies with requests over HTTPS if the cookie is marked “secure”. The application must be served over HTTPS for this to make sense.
```

for more [user-session-configs](https://superset.apache.org/docs/security/#user-sessions)

Comment: Thanks will try and revert

Comment: Thanks a ton..it worked @user1925936

Comment: beware, it`s make your application less secure.

Comment: getting the same issue, and really confused about why this is not accounted for - most people spin up outside of local for actual usecases

Answer (score 1):

I was using the latest superset docker image. Was facing the same problem. The problem was not solved even after commenting out the configurations as told by @user1925936. Turns out that this is a problem with the latest image. Got to know from [here](https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/24579).

The solution is to use the last stable docker image by adding the line below to the `docker-compose-non-dev.yml` file and running it using docker-compose command. 
 `x-superset-image: &superset-image apache/superset:2.1.0`

I was also wondering how to override the configurations when using a docker image. It can be done by making a copy of `./docker/pythonpath_dev/superset_config_local.example` into `./docker/pythonpath_dev/superset_config_docker.py` (git ignored) and fill in your overrides. [source](https://github.com/apache/superset/tree/master/docker#local-overrides)