# WARNING:root:Class 'werkzeug.local.LocalProxy in Supert Ubuntu EC2

Tags: apache-superset

after installing Apache Superset in Ubuntu AWS EC2, I had a problem that after logging in it redirected to the login screen again, I checked the logs and it was about CSRF, I commented out some lines in the config file and now after logging in I have the error "WARNING:root:Class 'werkzeug.local.LocalProxy' is not mapped", but I haven't found any solution yet.

I followed the superset [documentation](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-from-scratch/) and this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7hC85W3v5Q&ab_channel=SreyobhilashiIT), but always receiving this error.

There are some questions here that only talk about the first error, not the second :/
What is the case with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76629447/csrf-session-token-missing-in-apache-superset-ec2-instance) and [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71802579/while-logging-in-through-admin-in-apache-superset-it-redirects-me-back-to-login?rq=2) one?